# Using tidyverse to divide / split / break a variable into other variables by groups

Tags: r, dplyr, group-by, tidyverse, purrr

Let's say I have this kind of dataset

```
ds <- data.frame(group = c("A","B","C"),
                 value = rnorm(90,10,15))
```

Now, I want to use dplyr (or purrr + broom) to "divide" the value variable into three columns, like the following image.
[image: new dataset]

I've tried pivot_wider, group_split, and separate, but with no success.

In the future, I'll use these variables to compute correlation coefficients. 
I would like to remain in the tidyverse environment.
Thank you

Code:

```
ds <- data.frame(group = c("A","B","C"),
                 value = rnorm(90,10,15))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this can solve your problem:

```
df <- unstack(ds,value~group)
```

Answer (score 1):

Sticking to a `tidyverse` context as requested, the problem with `pivot_wider` is that there are duplicate row identifiers. Grouping by `group` doesn't solve that problem either. Personally I believe @Duck's solution is a viable one, but if you really want to stick to the tidyverse, [this](https://github.com/tidyverse/tidyr/issues/296#issuecomment-323062048) comment provides a workaround (and [this](https://www.daeconomist.com/post/2018-05-15-spread/) blog post discusses it in more detail). The idea is to add a unique row identifier with `row_number()`, then spreading the data:

```
ds %>% 
  group_by(group) %>% 
  mutate(grouped_id = row_number()) %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = group, values_from = value)
```

You can then remove or replace the `grouped_id` variable as desired.